# How to logout/change the current google account in Google Drive API?

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I'm programming a java desktop application (no android) that uses the Google Drive API.

The application mostly uses the Java Quickstart example (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java).
After logging in the first time, the API stores the user's credentials in a file called StoredCredential.

Now I would like to implement an option that allows the user to logout or change his google account.

My first instinct was to delete this StoredCredential file and like this, it works totally fine. But is there maybe another more stylistic way?

Greetings
Niklas

Comment: Deleting the stored you can't connect to the API anymore. The token previously generated will expired.

Comment: As I already mentioned, deleting the StoredCredential file works like a charme. I just would like to know whether there's a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

If your Auth Flow relies on Stored Credentials there are three ways to handle the Data Store to save the Access Token.
You can use:

- [AppEngineDataStoreFactory](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-http-client/latest/com/google/api/client/extensions/appengine/datastore/AppEngineDataStoreFactory.html): persists the credential using the Google App Engine Data Store API.
- [MemoryDataStoreFactory](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-http-client/latest/com/google/api/client/util/store/MemoryDataStoreFactory.html): "persists" the credential in memory, which is only useful as a short-term storage for the lifetime of the process.
- [FileDataStoreFactory](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-http-client/latest/com/google/api/client/util/store/FileDataStoreFactory.html): persists the credential in a file.

Using the FileDataStoreFactory pattern you will have either to delete or overwrite your file in order to remove the references to that credentials in your Application.

When building your Authorization code flow you can choose the logic that will store the credentials that better suites your application needs.

### References

[Authorization Code Flow](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2#authorization_code_flow)

[Google API OAuth2 with Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2)